# Getting the number of documents in a Solr Cloud collection

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm working on a custom Solr search component which takes into account the number of documents in the collection. Currently the number of documents is hard coded in my Solr configuration file, and that's bad because the number of documents is dynamic. Is it possible to get the number of documents (in the whole collection, not in a single core) from the response builder? So far I have found a way to get the cloud descriptor (`rb.req.getCore().getCoreDescriptor().getCloudDescriptor()`), but in contrast to my expectations I did not see a `getNumDocs()` method in there.

Comment: What does a `*:*` query return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code to get the NumberOfDocuments in my SOLR Cloud Collection.

```
HttpSolrServer httpSolrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/");
QueryResponse response = httpSolrServer.query(new SolrQuery(), METHOD.POST);    
SolrDocumentList solrDocumentList = queryResponse.getResults();
solrDocumentList.getNumFound();
solrDocumentList.getStart();
```

Hope this Helps you!!!